# latex3 clist put inside an environment definition

Tags: latex3, xparse

I'm puzzled as to why the following doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

 \ExplSyntaxOn
 \clist_new:N \l_test
 \clist_set:Nn \l_test {a,b,c}
\NewDocumentCommand{\putitem}{m}{
  \clist_put_right:Nn \l_test {#1}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foobar}{mm}{ FOO }{ BAR \putitem{##1}}
 \NewDocumentCommand{\giveitems}{}{\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_test {\fbox{##1}}}
 \ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

 \putitem{xyz}
 \putitem{asdf}
 \giveitems

\begin{foobar}{abab}{baba}
  XXX
\end{foobar}

\giveitems % output is the same as the earlier call
\end{document}
```

So as part of making the environment, an additional string should be added to the clist. But it doesn't work. I would expect the second `\giveitems` to have an additional item, namely `abab`. Replacing `\putitem` with its definition inside the new environment doesn't make any difference. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environments form groups, which means you'll need a global variable to see the result outside. At the same time, you need `#1` not `##1` when using the argument from your environment.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g__seamus_test_clist
\clist_set:Nn \g__seamus_test_clist {a,b,c}
\NewDocumentCommand{\putitem}{m}{
  \clist_gput_right:Nn \g__seamus_test_clist {#1}
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foobar}{mm}
  { FOO }
  { BAR \putitem{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\giveitems}{}
  {\clist_map_inline:Nn \g__seamus_test_clist {\fbox{##1}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: I've tided up the variable name here to follow standard `expl3` conventions

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! what convention requires double underscores after the `g` in the clist?

Comment: @Seamus Double underscores mean “private variable”, so not to be used by third parties.